# How to upload picture in dropzone with selenium on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium, capybara

I work with Capybara(2.4.4), Selenium-webdriver (2.47.0) and Firefox (39).

I should upload picture on click and drop element: http://screencast.com/t/jRCo4D0F

I used solution from [this article](http://blog.paulrugelhiatt.com/rails/testing/capybara/dropzonejs/2014/12/29/test-dropzonejs-file-uploads-with-capybara.html).

**In chrome** it works! But **in firefox not**!

It failed on line:

```
$('.dropzone')[0].dropzone.listeners[0].events.drop(e);
```

with error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: e is undefined
[remote server] https://master-site.somesitename.org/assets/account-d0fc2c2c.js:19:in `t</t.prototype.addFile'
[remote server] https://master-site.somesitename.org/assets/account-d0fc2c2c.js:18:in `t</t.prototype.handleFiles'
[remote server] https://master-site.somesitename.org/assets/account-d0fc2c2c.js:18:in `t</t.prototype.drop'
[remote server] https://master-site.somesitename.org/assets/account-d0fc2c2c.js:18:in `t</t.prototype.init/this.listeners<.events.drop</<'
[remote server] https://master-site.somesitename.org/en/my/products/68213/photos line 68 > Function:3:in `anonymous'
[remote server] https://master-site.somesitename.org/en/my/products/68213/photos:68:in `handleEvaluateEvent'
./framework/support/capybara_extension.rb:73:in `drop_in_dropzone'
./framework/ep-logic/guide_logic.rb:81:in `create_new_private_tour'
./spec/guide_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

I try to run every js in firebug console manually. All worked well and picture uploaded.

Please, need help! How fix pictures uploading in Firefox?

Comment: Add capybara, webdriver and firefox verisons, please.

Answer (score 0):

I am using c# with selenium to automate the image upload using javascript which is as follows 
`IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
  js.ExecuteScript("var myZone, blob, base64Image; myZone = Dropzone.forElement('#images-dropzone');" +
 @"base64Image = '';" +
"function base64toBlob(r,e,n){e=e||\"\",n=n||512;for(var t=atob(r),a=[],o=0;o<t.length;o+=n){for(var l=t.slice(o,o+n),h=new Array(l.length),b=0;b<l.length;b++)h[b]=l.charCodeAt(b);var v=new Uint8Array(h);a.push(v)}var c=new Blob(a,{type:e});return c}" +
"blob = base64toBlob(base64Image, 'image / png');" +
"blob.name = 'testfile.png';" +
"myZone.addFile(blob);"`

Let me explain how this thing works? we are targeting dropzone using its ID i.e. 'images-dropzone' in my case. you need to replace that with yours to work. We are passing a base64Image string and there are online tools which give you base64 output for images. pass your image string to @"base64Image. if required to generate base64 string dynamically let me know I can share code for that too. I hope this helps